# 90 Day Window +/- 14 Days Recurring and how to find matching records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using T-SQL and am looking to find some values using the 'simplest' query possible. By this I mean I would like to be able to do this logic in only one statement / where clause if possible.

A user has a baseline date (let's say 25th November 2016), and every 90 days (+/-14 days) a 'time window' opens that allows them to access some data. In this case it would be between the dates 9th Feb 2017 to 9th March 2017. This is an ongoing arrangement, and consequently 90 days (+/-14 days) after 23 Feb 2017 the same thing happens again.

I need to be able to calculate if a user is within any of these windows from only knowing the baseline date.

I was initially thinking of using `DATEDIFF(DAY, baseline_date, GETDATE()) % 90 = 0` but I realised that won't allow me to account for the +/- 14 days.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us some table structure. Sample data and expected output? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the days `-14 - 0` (before the zero) and `0 - 14` (after the zero).
The `% 90` will give values from `0` to `89` (no negatives). But because it cycles and resets at 90, the `-14 - 0` is the same as `76 - 89`.

So you want days `0 - 14` and `76 - 89`:

```
where datediff(day, baseline_date, GETDATE()) % 90 not between 15 and 75
```

Comment: This is great, though probably useful to note that I required another clause to make it work as expected:  `and datediff(day, baseline_date, GETDATE()) >= 90`